# Реализовать алгоритм по автоматам на Хаскеле

Tags: haskell

Мне нужно проверить, допускает ли автомат слово, которое состоит из одинаковых символов. Если хотя бы одно такое есть, то нужно вывести его, если нет - вывести "NO". Для каждого символа из входного алфавита мы запускаем поиск, и если мы пришли в финальный стан, то должны вывести это слово. Если мы дважды попали не в финальный стан, то прекратить поиск для конкретной буквы(попали в цикл). Я написал часть кода, создал тип автомат, но не знаю как реализовать сам алгоритм на haskell.

```
main = do { 
print(goal m1);
print(goal m2);
print(goal m3);
print(goal m4);
}

w = "abab" 
type FSM q = ([q], Alphabet, [Transition q], q, [q]) 
type Alphabet = [Char] 
type Transition q = (q, Char, q) 
 
     
m1 :: FSM Int 
m1 = ([0, 1, 2, 3], 
      ['a', 'b'], 
      [(0, 'a', 1), (1, 'a', 3), (2, 'a', 2), 
       (0, 'b', 2), (2, 'b', 3), (1, 'b', 1)], 
      0, 
      [3] 
    ) 
 
m2 :: FSM Int 
m2 = ([0, 1, 2, 3], 
      ['a', 'b'], 
      [(0, 'a', 1), (1, 'a', 3), (2, 'a', 2), 
       (0, 'b', 2), (2, 'b', 3), (1, 'b', 1), 
       (3, 'a', 3), (3, 'b', 3)], 
      0, 
      [3] 
    ) 
 
m3 :: FSM Int 
m3 = ([0, 1, 2, 3], 
      ['a', 'b'], 
      [(0, 'a', 1), (1, 'a', 3), (2, 'a', 2), 
       (0, 'b', 2), (2, 'b', 3), (1, 'b', 1), 
       (3, 'a', 1), (3, 'b', 3) ], 
      0, 
      [3] 
    ) 

m4 :: FSM Int 
m4 = ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
      ['a', 'b'], 
      [(0, 'a', 1), (1, 'a', 2), (2, 'a', 3), 
       (3, 'a', 5), (5, 'a', 4), (1, 'b', 1), 
       (3, 'b', 1), (3, 'b', 3) ], 
      0, 
      [4] 
    ) 
 
states :: FSM q -> [q] 
states (u, _, _, _, _) = u 
 
alph :: FSM q -> Alphabet 
alph (_, a, _, _, _) = a 
 
trans :: FSM q -> [Transition q] 
trans (_, _, t, _, _) = t 
 
start :: FSM q -> q 
start (_, _, _, s, _) = s 
 
final :: FSM q -> [q] 
final (_, _, _, _, f) = f

delta :: FSM Int -> Int -> Char -> Int 
delta m st symbol | length [q1 | (q0, x, q1) <- trans m, q0 == st, x == symbol] > 0 = [q1 | (q0, x, q1) <- trans m, q0 == st, x == symbol] !! 0 | otherwise = -1

goal:: FSM Int -> String
goal m = seek m (alph m) where
    seek m [] = "No"
    seek m (x:xs) | find_letter m x > 0 = create_word x (find_letter m x) [] | otherwise = seek m xs


find_letter:: FSM Int -> Char -> Int 
find_letter m s = dfs m s (start m) [start m] 0 where
    dfs m s state states count 
        | (delta m state s) elem states = 0 
        | (delta m state s) == -1 = 0 
        | (delta m state s) elem (final m) = count + 1
        | otherwise = dfs m s (delta m state s) (states++[delta m state s]) (count+1)
 
create_word:: Char -> Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
create_word symbol 0 list = list
create_word symbol count list = create_word symbol (count-1) (list++[symbol])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача сводится к поиску пути в ориентированном графе.
Например, для вашего случая `m1`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно найти один из путей из начального состояния (четвертое поле типа `FSM`) – вершины `0` на диаграмме, до одного из заключительных состояний (пятое поле типа `FSM`), в данном случае оно одно – это вершина `3`. При этом использовать только одинаково промаркированные ребра, например, только `a` или только `b`.

Т.е. алгоритм будет таким

- Берем один из символов алфавита, например, `a`
- Удаляем все ребра, промаркированные другими символами.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Ищем путь от вершины `0` до вершины `3` (например, поиском в ширину)

В данном случае это будет путь 0→1→3 через два ребра `a`, значит автомат допускает как минимум одну подходящую строку – `aa`

Если путь не найден, повторяем действия для других заключительных состояний и оставшихся символов.

---

#### Дополнение после правок в вопросе

Если не менять ваш алгоритм, получится примерно так

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe, listToMaybe)
import Data.Foldable (asum)
...

delta :: Eq a => FSM a -> a -> Char -> Maybe a
delta m st symbol = listToMaybe [q1 | (q0, x, q1) <- trans m, q0 == st, x == symbol]

goal :: Eq a => FSM a -> String
goal m = fromMaybe "No" $ asum [flip replicate x <$> find_letter m x | x <- alph m]

find_letter :: Eq a => FSM a -> Char -> Maybe Int
find_letter m s =  dfs (start m) [start m] 1
  where
    dfs state seen count =
      case delta m state s of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just nextState
          | nextState `elem` seen -> Nothing
          | nextState `elem` final m -> Just count
          | otherwise -> dfs nextState (nextState : seen) (count + 1)
```

Но имейте в виду, что в изначальном вопросе у вас был один недетерминированный автомат `m4`, и с ним, по понятной причине алгоритм не сработает.

От себя могу предложить такой вариант: Так как минимальное количество символов в допустимом слове у вас не может превысить количество состояний, можно просто скармливать автомату по одной букве, пока не достигнем заключительного состояния или пока не превысим количество узлов.

Вот пример для недетерминированного автомата.

```
m4 :: FSM Int
m4 = ([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
      ['a', 'b'],
      [(0,'a',1), (1,'b',1), (1,'a',4), (0,'a',3),
      (0,'b',2), (3,'b',2), (2,'b',5), (5,'a',5),
      (4,'b',6), (5,'a',6), (6,'b',3), (3,'a',5),
      (6,'a',7), (7,'b',7), (7,'a',4)],
      0,
      [7])

next :: Eq a => FSM a -> Char -> a -> [a]
next m char st = [to | (from, x, to) <- trans m, x == char, st == from]
```

```
GHCi> take (length (states m4)) $ iterate (nub . (>>= next m4 'a')) [start m4]
[[0],[1,3],[4,5],[5,6],[5,6,7],[5,6,7,4],[5,6,7,4],[5,6,7,4]]
GHCi> take (length (states m4)) $ iterate (nub . (>>= next m4 'b')) [start m4]
[[0],[2],[5],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Для буквы `a` заключительное состояние `7` достигается на пятом шаге, значит в слове 4 буквы `a`. Для буквы `b` заключительное состояние не достигается.

Comment: Так это понятно, мне код нужен) Вообще, я уже написал его, но он прямо скажем не очень

Comment: @user435351 "не очень" - это не страшно, приложите то, что есть к вопросу. Здесь не принято делать домашнюю работу за студентов, а помогать в написании - совсем другое дело.

Comment: обновил код, посмотрите, если можете - хотелось бы упростить функции

Comment: а можно узнать, как работает эта строчка:
goal m = fromMaybe "No" $ asum [flip replicate x <$> find_letter m x | x <- alph m] ?

Comment: @user435351 в случае `Maybe`, `asum` возвращает первый `Just` (из списка) или `Nothing`, если таких нет. `fromMaybe` возвращает первый аргумент, если второй - `Nothing`, иначе возвращает содержимое второго.

Comment: @user435351 `flip replicate x <$> m`, применяет функцию `flip replicate x`, т.е. `\y -> replicate y x` к содержимому `m`, если оно есть. иначе ничего не делает. т.е. `flip replicate 'x' <$> Just 5` = `Just (replicate 5 'x')`, `flip replicate 'x' <$> Nothing` = `Nothing`

Comment: @user435351 Другими словами, берем символы, делаем из них "возможно числа", из них "возможно строки", первую такую "точно строку" берем и возвращаем ее содержимое. Если таких не оказалось - возвращаем "No"

Comment: розобрался, но есть один момент - здесь мы будем находить все возможные варианты слов из одной буквы, и только потом брать первое слово. Можно ли "найти первое слово и тут же взять"?

Comment: @user435351 Не будем. ленивые вычисления же. Вычисление списка остановится на первом `Just`

Comment: тогда это круто)